# Stream a large file from http service

Tags: c#, .net, http, stream, flurl

I am writing a component to stream a large (4+ GB) from an HTTP service.  The component takes a URL and destination stream.  The destination stream could be a filestream or it could be a stream that POSTS to different HTTP service, or even both.  As the author of my component, I need to do these steps until I'm done:

1. read a reasonable-size buffer from the HTTP stream,
2. write this buffer to the destination stream,
3. flush the destination stream (out to disk, network, etc)

I should never have more than the size of the buffer of data in memory.

I am using flurl to make my HTTP calls to the server.  I've tried the following ways to make my call

```
var stream = await flurlClient.GetStreamAsync();
```

This gives me back a MemoryStream, which doesn't work as it'll fill up and take up as much memory as the size of the file.

```
var response = flurlClient.GetAsync();
var stream = response.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync();
```

Again, a memory stream.

```
var response = flurlClient.GetAsync();
var stream = new CustomFlushingSteam();
response.Content.CopyToAsync(stream);
```

This one looks promising, but alas, it tries to write the entire thing using a single Write() statement.

How can I accomplish this task without blowing up my memory? I'd prefer to use flurl, but I'm not tied to it.

Comment: Does flurl give you access to the underlying `NetworkStream`? If not, it won't work for this

Answer (score 7, accepted):

After doing some digging, I found that the following code solves my problem:

```
var response = flurlClient.SendAsync(
    HttpMethod.Get, null, null, HttpCompletionOption.ResponseHeadersRead);
var stream = response.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync();
```

In this case, the stream that comes back is no longer a memory stream but the network stream.

Comment: Yep, that's what you want to do. And it's what Flurl's [DownloadFileAsync](https://github.com/tmenier/Flurl/blob/master/src/Flurl.Http/DownloadExtensions.cs#L24) does internally.

Comment: For future readers, it is the `HttpCompletionOption.ResponseHeadersRead` that gives the magic here.